# Show prices only for a specific customer's country in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, geolocation, price

I've developed a catalogue using woocommerce, however I need to be able to **hide product prices from users who are visiting the site from outside of the UK** due to reasons outside of my control.

I've found plugins that allow me to change product prices based on visitor location, but nothing allows me to hide the prices.

Is there any plugins that I've missed or anything I can add in to the woocommerce files to achieve this?

Comment: Just hide the price or make it unpurchasable?

Comment: They are ready unpurchasable, I used a catalogue plugin for that, I just need to hide the prices now if the visitor is outside the UK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will **hide prices outside United kingdom** based on customer **geolocated country**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'country_geolocated_based_hide_price', 10, 2 );
function country_geolocated_based_hide_price( $price, $product ) {
    // Get an instance of the WC_Geolocation object class
    $geo_instance  = new WC_Geolocation();
    // Get geolocated user geo data.
    $user_geodata = $geo_instance->geolocate_ip();
    // Get current user GeoIP Country
    $country = $user_geodata['country'];

    return $country !== 'GB' ? '' : $price;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

If you want to enable that geolocated feature only for unlogged customers, use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'country_geolocated_based_hide_price', 10, 2 );
function country_geolocated_based_hide_price( $price, $product ) {
    if( get_current_user_id() > 0 ) {
        $country = WC()->customer->get_billing_country();
    } else {
        // Get an instance of the WC_Geolocation object class
        $geo_instance  = new WC_Geolocation();
        // Get geolocated user geo data.
        $user_geodata = $geo_instance->geolocate_ip();
        // Get current user GeoIP Country
        $country = $user_geodata['country'];
    }
    return $country !== 'GB' ? '' : $price;
}
```

> An updated version of this code is available [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54925321/3730754) avoiding a backend bug.
>
> I have added in the function on start:
>
> ```
> if ( is admin() ) return $price;
> ```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you, are there any other steps I need to take when implementing this? As since implementing this all my prices have been removed, despite me being in the UK myself.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried both solutions you posted, and both hide the prices in all locations, I set "Geolocate" in my WooCommmerce settings, I assume that's correct?

Comment: I've just been testing and the solution works excellently on the catalogue pages, however, when I navigate to an individual product page, the price still show?  is there a different identifier that I need to add to target that price element as well as the one on the catalogue page?

Comment: @Marcus I have tested this code on all woocommerce default product types (even variable products, bookable products and subscriptions) and all the price are hidden everywhere on all catalog archives pages and single product pages too. So there is some customization made by you or your theme or a plugin that is making trouble.

Comment: I've just found a bug: 

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_billing_country() on null in /var/sites/o/oxfordriderwear.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/storefront/functions.php:61 Stack trace: #0 /var/sites/o/oxfordriderwear.com/public_html/.... **
On the products tab in my admin area

Comment: @Marcus I am using on my test server the last WP and WC versions with storefront theme and I don't have any issue… `WC()->customer->get_billing_country();` is the correct way to get the current customer shipping address (I use it for a while everywhere without any problems).

Answer (score 2):

There are various web APIs that will help you. For example http://ipinfo.io

```
ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}")); 
echo $details->country; // -> "US"
```

If you have to do many checks a local database is better. MaxMind offer a [free database](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) that you can use with various PHP libraries, including [GeoIP](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.geoip.php).

Comment: For info, Woocommerce has already a strong geolocation feature in it's core: the `WC_Geolocation()` class and methods… So nothing external is required.