# Hide WooCommerce product details based on user location

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, globalization

I've developed a catalogue (non-purchasable products) using woocommerce, however I need to be able to hide product prices from users who are visiting the site from outside of the UK due to reasons outside of my control.

I am using *"[Hiding prices based on visitor location backend bug in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54924788/hiding-prices-based-on-visitor-location-backend-bug-in-woocommerce/54925321#54925321)"* *(an answer on my last question)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'country_geolocated_based_hide_price', 10, 2 );
function country_geolocated_based_hide_price( $price, $product ) {
    // Not on backend
    if( is_admin() ) 
        return $price;

    if( get_current_user_id() > 0 ) {
        $country = WC()->customer->get_billing_country();
    } else {
        // Get an instance of the WC_Geolocation object class
        $geo_instance  = new WC_Geolocation();
        // Get geolocated user geo data.
        $user_geodata = $geo_instance->geolocate_ip();
        // Get current user GeoIP Country
        $country = $user_geodata['country'];
    }
    return $country !== 'GB' ? '' : $price;
}
```

I've been testing this using:

- https://geopeeker.com/
- https://www.newipnow.com/

For the most part (according to these sites) this seems to be working, however I'm noticing some inconsistencies in the results. Some pages still seems to show the product prices. 
I fear that one of my plugins or custom CSS may be interfering but as I only have access to these websites to test, I can't be sure.

Website is: https://oxfordriderwear.com/product-category/mens/

Is there anything anyone can spot that could be causing this issue/know a way to find out? Or is there a more reliable way to test?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question. But I had a similar problem, so maybe this will help someone. I didn't use any plugins for this.
First of all, in woocommerce/settings/general enable default customer location - geolocate.[image: geolocation woocommerce]

And here is the code snippet you'll need. My problem was that I had to enable/disable specific product categories for SL and all other coutries.

```
$location = WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip();
$country = $location['country'];
if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE != 'sl' || $country != "SI") {
    function shop_loop_make_price_visibility(){
        global $post;
        $categories = array( 'tasting-kits', 'gift-packages', 'kompleti-za-degustacijo', 'darilni-paketi', 'degustacije', 'tastings' );
    
        if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $post->ID )) {
            add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10);
        } else{
            remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10);
        }
    }
    function shop_loop_make_surplus_add_to_cart(){
        global $post;
        $categories = array( 'tasting-kits', 'gift-packages','kompleti-za-degustacijo', 'darilni-paketi', 'degustacije', 'tastings' );
    
        if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $post->ID )) {
            add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 25);
        } else{
            remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 25);
        }
    }
    function shop_loop_make_singe_page_price(){
        global $post;
        $categories = array( 'tasting-kits', 'gift-packages','kompleti-za-degustacijo', 'darilni-paketi', 'degustacije', 'tastings'  );
    
        if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $post->ID )) {
            add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 20);
        } else{
            remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 20);
        }
    }

    add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'shop_loop_make_price_visibility', 8 );
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'shop_loop_make_surplus_add_to_cart', 8 );
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'shop_loop_make_singe_page_price', 9 );
}
```